# How to convert char array to uint8_t and print it in c?

Tags: c, char, clang, uint8t

I have a decimal number and we have converted it to hex and have stored in a hex array. After that I added a "0x" to this number (in fact char array). Now I want to convert this hex number (in char array) to Uint8_t and then print it. The first question is how this convert can be done and the second one is that in the process of printing, what print format (%02x, %d, %s , and ...) should be used?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're asking. What is a "hex array"? What does it mean to "add 0x to this number (in fact char array)? What do you mean by "convert char array to uint8_t"? What's the goal -- represent the data in a different form, print it, or both? Can you include code that you've already written, and a desired output for a given input?

Comment: It is unclear what a "hex array" is. Do you mean something like `char array[] = "0xA5";`? If that is the case, then please [edit] the question to provide an example. This will make your question clearer.

Comment: As for the second question, you forgot to say what output you want.

Comment: Convert hex chars by calling strtol. Print using whichever output base you need.

Comment: @PaulHankin In short, what I currently have in my code is a char array that contains the value of "0x8A" (8A is just an example). Now I want to convert it to uint8_t type so that, for example, I have a value in the form of 0x8A in a variable with the uint8_t type.

Comment: @WeatherVane In short, what I currently have in my code is a char array that contains the value of "0x8A" (8A is just an example). Now I want to convert it to uint8_t type so that, for example, I have a value in the form of 0x8A in a variable with the uint8_t type.

Comment: `uint8_t x = strtol(arr, 0, 16); printf("0x%02x", x);`

Answer (score 1):

This example converts the hex string to an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void)
{
    int val;
    char str[] = "0x12";
    int res = sscanf(str, "%i", &val);
    printf("res=%d val=%d\n", res, val);
}
```

Program output

```
res=1 val=18
```

The `%i` format is used in `scanf` function family to accept input in decimal, octal (with a leading 0) or hex (with leading 0x). If you only want to accept decimal use `%d` or `%u`.